# Error trying to use getLine() in C to read stdin

Tags: c, compiler-errors, stdin, getline

I am using this function of C to read a user input (stdin) with the getLine() function. This function returns a char* with the user input. This is the segment:

```
char * rline(void)
{

char *line;
size_t buff = 0; 
char * getLine(&line, &buff, stdin);
return line;

}
```

However, when it is run, this error is displayed and it does not compile.

```
error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '&' token
```

I looked around but can't quite figure out why this is happening, is my syntax correct or is it a logical error?

Comment: Just read how to use a function in C: https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-functions

Comment: @Abend thanks, but i am familiar with calling functions, how do you think I intended on calling this one?

Comment: @DavidBowling i am not using POSIX, but thank you. I tried both getline() and getLine() but both return the same error: undefined reference.

Comment: Ah i see- i have included #define _GNU_SOURCE at the top of my header and also tried #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L - both still give me the same error(undefined reference)

Comment: I couldn't figure it out- I changed my approach to avoid getline altogether. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling that function wrong. The `char *` has nothing to do there before your function call, it is only needed in the declaration of the function.

Example of a proper function declaration :

```
char * getLine(char *, int, int);
```

Example of a proper function call :

```
getLine(&line, &buff, stdin);
```

By the way, I think the buffer's size is yours to chose, by setting a value to the second parameter.

Comment: Thank you, however when I declare the function in my header(and if i don't), and then attempt to call it, it gives me error "undefined reference to getLine()" , why is that so?

Comment: @JohnStawket there is no standard function called `getLine`

Comment: @ErikW Is there not? [This is the man page for getline(3), included in <stdio.h>](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline). I have tried both getline() & getLine() but both give the same error: undefined reference.

Comment: @JohnStawket it is a POSIX function. You should prefer to use standard functions. If you really want to use `getline`, write this: `#define _GNU_SOURCE` above `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: I have that written at the top of my header but I still get the undefined reference error.

Comment: @JohnStawket Are you on windows?

Comment: I couldn't figure it out- I changed my approach to avoid getline altogether. Thank you for your help. BTW the code is being run on Sunsparc unix SunOS 5.10 generic January 2005(my university's, I know its old)